# How can i integrate laravel with magento?

Tags: laravel, magento2

I want to create a functionality where back-end is created in laravel. And, user interact with la-ravel's back-end and any information passed should be saved in magento 2 using APIs.
Is it possible to create this kind of the structure?

Answer (score 1):

Why Not bro, It's Obviously possible. 
You have to just create a CRUD API in your Magento-2.
That's it.

Comment: Thanks !  can you please guide me little more regarding

Comment: you can check the following links for details to know about CRUD  API creation on Magento-2
[Medium](https://medium.com/@kangpaper/crud-models-in-magento-2-4e031861909b)
and
[Alan Storm](https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_crud_models_for_database_access/)